# HorizontalAligment on Rectangle not working when changed programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a new user control. My control extends a StackPanel, and for now consists of another StackPanel in which I'm adding some Rectangles. I would like the inner StackPanel to be horizontally centered within the control, and the Rectangles to be vertically aligned with  the bottom of the inner StackPanel. My code is below, but it results in the inner StackPanel aligned to the left of the control, and the Rectangles are aligned at the top of the inner StackPanel.

```
public partial class ComponentStacker : StackPanel
{
    private StackPanel tokenHolder; 

    public ComponentStacker(int numTokens)
    {
        this.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        tokenHolder = new StackPanel(); 

        this.Children.Add(tokenHolder);

        tokenHolder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkKhaki);
        tokenHolder.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        for (int i = 0; i < numTokens; i++)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.Width = 15;
            rect.Height = 10;
            rect.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 0);
            rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            rect.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;

            this.tokenHolder.Children.Add(rect);
        }

        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Goldenrod);
        this.Margin = new Thickness(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first question is : why not add the rectangle directly to your stackPanel ?
i mean no tokenHolder stuff and :
    this.Children.Add(rect);
instead of 
    this.tokenHolder.Children.Add(rect);

Switch on the code helped me for those kind of things :
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-creating-a-custom-panel-control

Comment: Mostly because I intend to add other items to the stackPanel later. Thanks for the pointer; I don't immediately see anything about alignment but will continue to look deeper.

Comment: In fact i had so much issues with StackPanel not being well aware of its size/content/... i only use Grid now. Maybe that would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It's the line:

```
this.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
```

When I changed it to Orientation.Vertical, the inner tokenPanel centered nicely.